# React js add logo in qrcode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, qr-code

I would like to be able to create a qrcode with a custom logo, as seen in the image.

I currently use the following library in react js: `qrcode.react`
to create the qr code, but does not allow you to insert a logo.

I thought of writing a module to be able to do it, but I wanted some suggestions about it, as far as I can remember the internal codes, that is those where I should put the logo are correction codes.

I also found the following site that allows you to customize your qr code, according to you what technique they use, link: [Site](https://www.qrcode-monkey.com/)

[image]

Comment: Hi Paul

Have you able to accomplished the above QR Code?
I'm looking for similar QR Code

Answer (score 2):

Reading qrcode.react documentation, I saw imageSetings prop, this is alow you to insert any image you want as logo. Try it, this work for me:

```
<QRCode
  value="http://facebook.github.io/react/"
  fgColor="#7f0000"
  includeMargin
  imageSettings={{
    src:"https://picsum.photos/id/67/300/300",
    excavate:true
  }}
/>
```